# Ruby: `require': cannot load such file

Tags: rubygems

Environment: ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
Just upgraded From Mageia 6 to Mageia 7 (in-situ, not fresh install)
A Ruby program that worked under Mageia 6 now refuses with error message:

> `require': cannot load such file -- sequel (LoadError)

I have researched this error (pretty frequent on Stackoverflow!) but can't see a solution that pertains.
From 'gem environment'

```
 - GEM PATHS:  
     - /home/graeme/.gem/ruby/2.5.0  
     - /usr/share/gems  
     - /usr/local/share/gems
```

But it's there:

```
[graeme@bach Scripts]$ cd /usr/local/share/gems/gems  
[graeme@bach gems]$ ls -l  
total 20  
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  1 18:14 bigdecimal-1.4.4/  
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  1 18:12 mini_portile2-2.4.0/  
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec  1 18:14 nokogiri-1.10.5/  
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  3 15:39 pg-1.1.4/  
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec  4 12:29 sequel-5.27.0/
```

Using the full path doesn't help either:

```
require '/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sequel'
```

Would appreciate some help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gem environment` looks correct, so I'm not sure why that isn't working.  You could try the following:

```
$: << '/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/'
require 'sequel'
```

You'd need to repeat that for each gem you want to load.  This is basically what rubygems normally does for you.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for replying. Did that, result negative.